# Error in Caret unable to find an inherited method for function ‘"NaiveBayes"’

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm running a toy example to run a Naive Bayer classifier using caret:

```
library(caret)
library(klaR)
# load the iris dataset
data(iris)
# define an 80%/20% train/test split of the dataset
split=0.80
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p=split, list=FALSE)
data_train <- iris[ trainIndex,]
data_test <- iris[-trainIndex,]
# train a naive bayes model
model <- NaiveBayes(Species~., data=data_train)
# make predictions
x_test <- data_test[,1:4]
y_test <- data_test[,5]
predictions <- predict(model, x_test)
# summarize results
confusionMatrix(predictions$class, y_test)
```

It used to work last time I run it about 4 months ago but now I'm getting this error when I try to `predict`

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘predict’ for signature ‘"NaiveBayes"’

I'm using "R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)"
But had the same error with a previous version, so I updated it to 4.05 to see if it was a problem of the version

It looks as if something changed in the predict function.

My package versions are:

```
packageVersion("caret") [1] ‘6.0.86’ 
packageVersion("klaR") [1] ‘0.6.15’
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. My package versions are `packageVersion("caret") 6.0.86` and `packageVersion("klaR") 0.6.15` .

Comment: My packageVersions are the same: packageVersion("caret")
[1] ‘6.0.86’
> packageVersion("klaR")
[1] ‘0.6.15’

Comment: Does `klaR:::predict.NaiveBayes(model, x_test)` still error?

Comment: Now it works fine!! Thank you!!

Comment: okay so it seems like you may have overwritten the `predict` function and are maybe loading a previous workspace with this? Try removing .Rdata and .rds files from your home directory.

Comment: Thanks! should I use this? rm(list = ls())

Comment: I suppose if you ran that immediately after restarting R it may work. A better solution is to not load previous workspaces, which would involve deleting files (that have the .Rdata and .rds extensions) from your working directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked!!!! If you paste it as an answer I could accept it becasue it was a good answer.. perhaps it was a naive question..

Comment: Please feel free to write an answer ... you know best what the issue was on your system

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else with the same problem in the future: the predict function was overwritten in my workspace so the problem was fixed cleaning the workspace in RStudio.

Thanks @user20650